# Url path level by using React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I get working this path `admin/users/:id` by using **react-router-dom**??

I have no problem when the level is just one, I mean something like: `/users/:id`

**Router:**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Container fluid={true} className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => <h1>DashBoard</h1>} />
              <Route path="/admin/users" component={AdminUsers} />
              //Below line is not working as I expect.
              <Route path="/admin/users/:id" render={() => <h1>User View</h1>} />
              <Route path="/admin/clients" render={() => <h1>Admin Clients</h1>} />
              <Route path="/reporting" component={AdminReportPage} />
              <Route path="/help" render={() => <h1>Help</h1>} />
              <Route render={() => <h1>Page not found.</h1>} />
            </Switch>
          </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

when I try to go to `admin/users/:id` the application doesn't respond and stay in `admin/users`.

> Extra: "react-router-dom": "4.3.1"

Answer (score 1):

Put exact attribute for "/admin/users"
i.e:

```
<Route exact path="/admin/users" component={AdminUsers} />
```